# PL/SQL - Trigger: Posso ver toda a linha atualizada em uma trigger after de linha?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou estudando PL/SQL na faculdade e o professor passou umas questões baseadas no modelo de Recursos Humanos do próprio OracleXE. A questão que estou fazendo pede uma trigger que impeça que um funcionário tenha o salário maior que o de seu chefe. E para essa trigger eu preciso de uma package com umas procedures para não dar erro de trigger mutante.

Essa foi a package que escrevi:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CONSULT_EMPLOYEE_SALARY IS

PROCEDURE LIMPA_VETOR IS
BEGIN
    idx := 0;
    v_tab.DELETE;
END;

PROCEDURE ALIMENTAR_VETOR (p_id EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE, p_salary EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE, p_managerID EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    idx := idx + 1;
    v_tab(idx).EMPLOYEE_ID := p_id;
    v_tab(idx).SALARY := p_salary;
    v_tab(idx).MANAGER_ID := p_managerID;
END;

PROCEDURE OBTER_VETOR (p_idx PLS_INTEGER, p_employeeID OUT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE, p_salary OUT EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE, p_managerID OUT EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    IF v_tab.EXISTS(p_idx) THEN
        p_employeeID := v_tab(idx).EMPLOYEE_ID;
        p_salary := v_tab(idx).SALARY;
        p_managerID := v_tab(idx).MANAGER_ID;
    END IF;
END; 
END;
```

E essa é a trigger que executa a procedure ALIMENTAR_VETOR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_AU AFTER UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN
    CONSULT_EMPLOYEE_SALARY.ALIMENTAR_VETOR(:OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID, :NEW.SALARY, :OLD.MANAGER_ID) ;
END IF;
END;
```

Quando testo o update ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Erro a partir da linha : 249 no comando -
update employees set salary = 9500 where employee_id = 104
Relatório de erros -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: erro: valor-chave de tabela de índice NULL numérico ou de 
valor
ORA-06512: em "HR.CONSULT_EMPLOYEE_SALARY", line 12
ORA-06512: em "HR.EMPLOYEE_AU", line 3
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'HR.EMPLOYEE_AU'
```

Eu pesquisei sobre esse erro, mas a mensagem que encontrei relacionada a esse código ORA é diferente. Isso está dizendo que estou passando um parâmetro nulo? E também estou em dúvida se é possível ter acesso a todas colunas em uma trigger after de linha usando :old.[nome-da-coluna].

Obrigado.

Comment: O vetor teria de ser alimentado antes da utilização da trigger , não conheço esta técnica com package mas creio que dará erro na carga se executada durante a trigger.O teste em si (ganhar mais que o chefe) não foi feito.... piada off topic , está trigger não vale para o PSG ... :)

Comment: Sim, existe uma trigger before de sentença que limpa o vetor. E a cada linha atualizada é para esses valores serem incluídos no vetor. E há uma outra trigger after de setença onde ocorre o teste do salário, mas nem chega a executar essa pois o erro ocorre nessa de alimentar o vetor

Comment: É possível ver o "old" na trigger de after sim .